# VirtoCommerce Setup admin not loading

Tags: c#, .net, virtocommerce

Trying to set up VirtoCommerce per docs here: https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/platform-deployment/deploy-from-source-code

Solution builds fine but when starting debugger I get:
[image]

Doesn't even hit a breakpoint in Startup.cs. 
When going via browser: http://localhost/admin, it spins endlessly. 
Tried iisreset /restart, nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. For some reason no exceptions were trown and no timeouts. Simply endless loading of the page. The issue was here:

```
SetupDatabaseInitializer.cs
```

at this line:

```
var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(_config);
```

I had incorrect connection string to my DB.